# Getting EntityFramework to send OR Column IS NULL

Tags: linq-to-entities, entity-framework-6

I have the following query (basically):

```
var row = _data.Rows
               .Where(access => (access.Column == request.Column
                                 || access.Column == null));
```

This is currently translating into something along these lines:

```
SELECT *
FROM [Rows] AS [Extent1]
WHERE ([Extent1].[Column] = @p__linq__0)
```

Now, my question is, why does this not translate into `[Extent1].[Column] = @p__linq__0 OR [Extent1].[Column] IS NULL`, and how do I make it do so?

Comment: What's the type of `access.Column`?

Comment: @MarcinJuraszek:  It's a `string` in C# and a `VARCHAR(64)` in SQL.

Comment: This is also going against a view, not a table, if that affects the behavior.

Answer (score 0):

If it is a varchar it will not show up as null, it will simply be empty, try this:

```
var row = _data.Rows.Where(access => 
    (string.IsNullOrEmpty(access.Column)  || access.Column == request.Column));
```

Comment: So, this translates to `(((LEN([Extent1].[Column])) = 0) OR ([Extent1].[Column] = @p__linq__0))`, which doesn't work because `Column` is `NULL`, and `LEN(NULL)` is `NULL` rather than `0`.

Answer (score 0):

The issue was that `Column` was part of the key defined for the entity, because EF wouldn't let me have the view without a key.  If I remove it from the key, it seems to work for my current needs - though, if it returns multiple results with the same key, they will all be the same (you lose any differences in the non-key column).  So, not a great solution, but it works.  Other options would be to add a surrogate key to the view or to use a stored procedure.

**EDIT**:  Going with the surrogate key on the view because having the key be inaccurate didn't sit well with me.